# Connect Android with database

Tags: android, mysql, xampp, voting

I am doing an academical project on Electronic Voting and I need to connect Android application with my MySQL database designed in xammp. Also, I am using the eclipse program in order to do my project.

Could you help me to find the way to connect android with xammp?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the application to connect to the database on a webserver then it might be best to create a REST service on the webserver and then access it via that.

Comment: can you explain more please ??

Answer (score 0):

A sample code here

```
private static String loginURL = "http://xxxx/databasename/index.php";//databasename as in xampp
//note:xxxx=10.0.2.2 for emulator,
//xxxx=ip address from ipconfig cmd if android device on same network as pc.

public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TAG", "SampleLogin"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(loginURL,"POST", params);
    return json;
}
```

To share internet from PC itself,use windows virtual wifi router and share your pc internet to android device.
 For android device to access tables,Ensure you've given access rights{edit httpd-xampp.conf to   "Allow from all" instead of " Require local" inside  tag}